# Trouble Calling Stored Procedure from BackgroundWorker

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asynchronous

I'm in ASP.NET MVC and am (mostly) using Entity Framework.  I want to call a stored procedure without waiting for it to finish.  My current approach is to use a background worker.  Trouble is, it works fine without using the background worker, but fails to execute with it.
In the DoWork event handler when I call 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
it just "disappears" (never gets to next line in debug mode).
Anyone have tips on calling a sproc asynchronously?  BTW, it'll be SQL Azure in production if that matters; for now SQL Server 2008.

```
    public void ExecAsyncUpdateMemberScoreRecalc(MemberScoreRecalcInstruction instruction)
    {
        var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(AsyncUpdateMemberScoreRecalc_DoWork);
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(instruction);
    }


    private void AsyncUpdateMemberScoreRecalc_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var instruction = (MemberScoreRecalcInstruction)e.Argument;

        string connectionString = string.Empty;
        using (var sprocEntities = new DSAsyncSprocEntities())  // getting the connection string
        {
            connectionString = sprocEntities.Connection.ConnectionString;
        }

        using (var connection = new EntityConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            EntityCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = DSConstants.Sproc_MemberScoreRecalc;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DSConstants.Sproc_MemberScoreRecalc_Param_SageUserId, instruction.SageUserId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DSConstants.Sproc_MemberScoreRecalc_Param_EventType, instruction.EventType);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DSConstants.Sproc_MemberScoreRecalc_Param_EventCode, instruction.EventCode);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DSConstants.Sproc_MemberScoreRecalc_Param_EventParamId, instruction.EventParamId);

            int result = 0;
            //  NEVER RETURNS FROM RUNNING NEXT LINE (and never executes)... yet it works if I do the same thing directly in the main thread.
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a try catch around the call and see if any exceptions are caught and are thus aborting the thread.

```
try {
     result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   // Log this error and if needed handle or 
   throw;
}
```

Comment: So simple, yet so true...  I had a try/catch on the outside but it never bubbled up that far for some reason.  Turns out it was something basic and so the code above does in fact do the trick.  For those looking to do this with EF, the other thing I needed to do to make it work was to use a separate edmx file and only call it from the async thread.